# Craecion Agenda Medica en Java

Tags: java

Quiero pregunatar .estoy haciendo un programa de odontologia en java se pero la agenda no se como realizarla ,quiro que al dar un dia en el calendario me muestre las horas de ese dia para registrar la cita,No se como hacer las tablas para realizar esta accion utilizaria un calendario para hacerla.Agradesco toda suu ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Deberias ser mas claro. Cual es el problema? la base de datos, la vista? que es lo que probaste o hiciste hasta ahora?

Comment: Gracias Por tu respuesta quiero seleccionar un dia del calendario y que me muestra las horas de ese dia

Comment: Perfecto Jesus.. mira los links que te pase. Debes demostrar que hiciste hasta ahora.. y como es que quieres generar eso, ya que hay montones de formas..

Comment: Te voy a enviar lo que quiero,no veo los link que enviaste

Comment: Los links son la informacion respectiva al sitio en mi primer comantario.